# Getting Timeout Expired Error running subprocess with shell=True

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code

```
COMMAND = ["base64", "--decode", "myKey", ">", "myKey.decoded"]

try:
    subprocess.check_call(COMMAND,shell=True, timeout=5)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as an_err:
    print("Exception encountered :: ", an_err.returncode)
    raise
```

But I am getting error executing it

```
subprocess.TimeoutExpired: Command '['base64', '--decode', 'myKey', '>', 'myKey.decoded']' timed out after 5 seconds
```

Any reason why I am getting timeout issue?

Running the command locally in linux works though.

Comment: There's no need to call out to `subprocess` to do this. Use the Python library. The timeout is because your call is hanging, or needs longer.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean? I placed the timeout=30 but still getting TimeoutExpired Error.

Comment: Why don't you simply use [`base64.b64decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.b64decode) instead of trying to debug this issue?

Comment: I mean, the command is waiting indefinitely for some reason. It may be trying to read from `stdin`. I don't have your system so I can't  reproduce your problem but it's clear there is an error in the command. Bear in mind you are using a relative path for the executable and the working directory is almost certainly not what you expect. Have you tried typing the command at a command line? Are you sure the program's parameters are the same in both systems? The problem is not because of `shell=True`. The problem is the command is incorrect for the target system.

Comment: I currently am playing around the subprocess module so I deliberately use the subprocess command instead of the Python Library.  I tried it in two linux box but the output is the same.  It still hangs for some unknown reason.